# Increased iOS app memory use under BES12?

Tags: ios, ipad, blackberry

We have an Enterprise iOS app that we deploy to clients as an IPA file.  Most of our clients to date are using AirWatch, and we've had no issues.  We also use AirWatch internally for deployment without issue.

A recent client,however, is using BES12 and started to complain that app crashes constantly.  After testing the exact copy of the app they're using, on identical iPads we could not reproduce the crash.  We then removed AirWatch from a couple of iPads, and enrolled in their BES12 system - and voila, the app crashes frequently.

In all of the profiling we've done, our app's maximum memory usage was ~350MB.  The crash logs from the BES12 deployed app show it 700MB before being terminated.  Crash log snippet:

```
{
"uuid" : "removed-for-stack-overflow-post",
"states" : [
  "frontmost",
  "resume"
],
"killDelta" : 4818,
"lifetimeMax" : 108090,
"age" : 434859705756,
"purgeable" : 74,
"fds" : 100,
"genCount" : 0,
"coalition" : 634,
"rpages" : 179571,
"reason" : "per-process-limit",
"pid" : 550,
"idleDelta" : 9921968212,
"name" : "removed-for-stackoverflow-post",
"cpuTime" : 2393.154223
}
```

Talking through the BES12 deployment with out client, there is a setting 'Convert Personal App to Work App' where they're selecting 'convert.'  Apparently this is necessary for the BES system to control/remove the app later on.

Looking for any ideas why the app would suddenly use so much more memory under BES12?